# Inserting Current Timestamp from Kafka Rest to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, timestamp, confluent-platform

I have managed to setup the Open Source Confluent Platform to work with Cassandra using the Cassandra Sink and it worked to send some simple data from Kafka-Rest to Cassandra. However, I would like to send data that contains a timestamp. It did not work from Kafka-Rest to have a schema with timestamp, neither did it with a string field instead. Is it possible to send timestamp data like that and if yes what should be modified? The KCQL or the Avro message?

It would be preferable to send only data that is not a timestamp and then Kafka or Cassandra would insert the current timestamp for the timestamp field.

Comment: Are you using the v1 or v2 REST API endpoints?

Comment: The ones on Confluent 3.2.1

Comment: Ok that supports 0.10 Kafka with timestamps if you use the V2 REST API of the REST Proxy but it won't if you use the older V1 REST Endpoints. What is the exact URL endpoint you are using?

Comment: It is version 2.

Comment: Ok then the Kafka message should have a timestamp in it already. Not in the message payload but in the Kafka protocol header. Now you just need to figure out how to extract the timestamp and insert it with the message value into Cassandra. I don't know this connector will enough to know if KCQL supports this function but the data should be there. If you need to check you can use `kafkacat` which supports printing timestamps (as kafka-console-consumer does not)